What is the `ssh -X` equivalent for Wayland?
An answer to How to forward X over SSH to run graphics applications remotely? explains how to forward GUI applications via an X11-compliant display server (like XOrg).
However, I see no equivalent for accessing remote systems using solely Wayland compositors on both ends. Does it exist, or must a combination of X11 and/or XWayland and Wayland be utilized?

waypipe is the closest equivalent. It is not raw Wayland-over-SSH, as Wayland is not primarily a network-oriented protocol – as I understand, it relies heavily on shared memory (whereas in X11 that's completely optional) – but it's probably as close as you can get.
$ waypipe ssh foo@bar

Some compositors, such as GNOME Shell, now integrate RDP and/or VNC directly into the compositor; it's likely to provide better performance.

same problem here but your solution causes "WAYLAND_DISPLAY not set, exiting". Do you have more details ?

@user3732793: Do you get the message from local waypipe  or from the remote program?

in the local console when conneting to the remote machine like that

@user3732793: And are you running a Wayland environment locally?

oh man that was thright question. Struggeld to connect through ssh and some one did say Ubuntu 22.04 now has wayland.... but only the remote machine has it. local is x11. is there a solution to it ?

@user3732793: It has Wayland for its remote display, but nearly all of the actual apps you'd be running are either dual X11/Wayland compatible or even X11-only, so if that's what you're looking for – just use ssh -X -Y. (After all, the whole point of X11 forwarding is that it doesn't use the remote display – it connects to your local one – so whether the remote display is Wayland or X11 does not matter.) Just keep the https://superuser.com/q/1843704 issue in mind when doing so.

@user3732793: also, Ubuntu uses basically GNOME, which actually has RDP (and VNC) support built in, so if you wanted instead to connect to the remote display as-is, you could enable "gnome-remote-desktop" for that.

In theory yes but what ever I try e.g. gedit opens on the remote desktop. Even if I follow your link and set the GDB_BACKEND=x11. If I export DISPLAY=myip:Display I get "Could not open X Display'. If possible I would like to avoid RDP/VNC and just use ssh to start apps with UI if needed remotely.
